# Ubuntu 12.04 I'm trying to ugrade my Geforce 8400 to Geforce GTX 560, getting a black screen

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have an NVidia Geforce 8400 which is working fine in Ubuntu 12.04.  I have just purchased an NVidia GeForce GTX 560 and have been trying to install it.  No matter what I do all I get is a black screen on boot up.
I have tried; 
1/ Additional Drivers, driver version 295.40, this works for the GeForce 8400 but gives me a black screen with the GTX 560 when I boot.
2/ Downloaded driver version 295.40 from NVidias site, was able to install it successfully, it works with my 8400 but gives me a black screen with the GTX 560 when I boot.

Are there any options I can try?

Comment: I think I have found the problem; not enough power going to the card.  This model is GV-N56GOC-1CI  "The GV-N56GOC-1CI is a performance optimized high-end card.  Power is taken from the PCI Express host bus as well as the external pwer connectors."
"Connect two 6-pin PCI Express auxiliary power connectors coming from the computer power supply to the connectors on the top edge of the GeForce GTX 560 graphics card".
My power supply is old and doesnt have 6-pin PCI Express auxiliary power connectors, so I will need to upgrade my power supply!

Answer (score 1):

The GTX 560 will draw ~250 watts of power from your power supply while the 8400 is ~70 watts. There technically needs to be 2 x 12 volt + rails at >20 amps to operate that bad boy!

What is the max output of your power supply?